# Looking for a Japanese ↔ English electronic dictionary

Tags: portable

I would like to buy a Japanese ↔ English electronic dictionary.

The trouble is, there are simply too many models available, and I don't know which have the features that are relevant to me.

My criteria are as follows:

- English dictionary data is US English
- Includes audio for English pronunciation (US English)
- Interface is easy and intuitive enough for an 8-year-old kid to use
- Japanese has handwriting input (via finger or stylus) for kanji lookup
- Includes English word definitions in English (not *only* Japanese translations)
- Includes Japanese word definitions in Japanese (not *only* English translations)
- Is durable and long-lasting
- Has good battery efficiency (doesn't require frequent replacement)
- An "add to favorites" word list (with flashcard functionality) would be a plus

The screen does not need to be in color. (Although color is okay if it doesn't significantly impact the battery life.)

The definitions do not need to include images. But if they do, this is okay.

I'm flexible on the price range, but don't want to overpay for features that don't matter to me. It should be reasonable. I expect it should be possible to get something good for well under ¥30,000. I've seen some for around ¥6,000 for example, so I know there's a broad price range and it varies depending on the features.

I don't think any other fancy features are necessary, but if there's something I left out that I should consider, feel free to suggest it. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can get an ereader and install a dictionary on that?

Comment: @Irsu85 Thanks for the suggestion. What advantage would that provide over a standard electronic dictionary? I'm not very familiar with e-readers, but I think kanji stroke input would be a no-go.

Comment: I don't have any experience with electronic dictionaries (didn't know those existed) but you can put more books on an ereader than just your dictionary